# Print even and odd from different threads using condition variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying to print like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,..... but even and odd numbers from two different threads. Also I want to make this program using condition variables.
I have created the following program, it just prints the odd parts and hangs up (may be dead lock..I do not know).
Please tell me what is the problem in my implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#define MAX 25
using namespace std;

mutex mu;
condition_variable cv;

void printodd()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
            cout <<"Odd : "<< i << endl;
            locker.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void printeven()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
            cv.wait(locker);
            cout <<"Even : "<< i << endl;
            locker.unlock();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(printodd);
    thread th2(printeven);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because notifications are not queued. This means that if `notify_one()` is called and there are no currently waiting threads, this notify is simply  lost. You see `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.....` because first thread completed even faster than second thread started. After second thread is started, it goes immediately into waiting which lasts forever (deadlock).

More than that, even if notifications were queued (hypotethically), then you would first see `1` from the first thread and only than `0` from the second thread (after it would have received notification).

You need to create two mutexes/conditional variables (one per each thread) and call the very first notify from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers in their analysis of the cause of the problem (the lack of notification queuing), but disagree that two instances of synchronization objects are required.

Your problem is one of a producer-consumer queue, with the producer and consumer alternating each iteration. A single mutex and condition is sufficient for a producer consumer queue. The following slight modifications to your code make it work:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<thread>
    #include<mutex>
    #include<condition_variable>


    #define MAX 25
    using namespace std;


    mutex mu;
    condition_variable cv;
    bool even = true;

    void print_it(int k)
    {
        const auto is_even = k % 2 == 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == k)
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
                cv.wait(locker, [is_even](){return even == is_even;});
                cout <<": "<< i << endl;
                even = !even;
                locker.unlock();
                cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        thread th0(print_it, 0);
        thread th1(print_it, 1);
        th0.join();
        th1.join();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two condition variables: one for the odd numbers and one for even numbers.

Each thread must wait on it's own condition, once that one is available, print its own next number, then notify the other thread via that ones condition variable and wait to be unlocked by the other thread again once that one has done its job.

To get things started, the "odd" condition variable must be notified once after the creation of the threads to print the first "one".